# webBrowser control stop javascript alert from website

Tags: c#, javascript

Im developing a Windows Forms application in VS 2010 C# with webbrowser control.
My goal is to automate navigating in this website, but when im in a certain point the website will popup a javascript alert that will stop the automation until i press the OK button.
I kinda solved the problem by simulating enter press when it popped up but the application should remain focused in order for it to work.
My question is, is there any way to kill this custom javascript alert from the website(i dont have access to the side, kill it from client side) so it doesnt show up or any other way to fix this problem?
The javascript alert(messagebox) that shows up is not an error, is a javascript alert that the programmers of that website put there for some reason.

Comment: A little googling found this: http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/webbrowser-control-prevent-window-alert/

Answer (score 0):

You can try consuming the `Navigated` event and intercepting the `DocumentText` prior to page loading to remove the `alert(...);` references.

From the `Navigated` page on the MSDN:

> Handle the `Navigated` event to receive notification when the `WebBrowser` control has navigated to a new document. When the `Navigated` event occurs, the new document has begun loading, which means you can access the loaded content through the `Document`, `DocumentText`, and `DocumentStream` properties.

Here's some code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Your.App
{
    public class PopupSuppress
    {
        WebBrowser _wb;
        public PopupSupress()
        {
            _wb = new WebBrowser();
            _wb.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(_wb_Navigated);
        }

        void _wb_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            string alertRegexPattern = "alert\\([\\s\\S]*\\);";
            //make sure to only write to _wb.DocumentText if there is a change.
            //This will prompt a reloading of the page (and another 'Navigated' event) [see MSDN link]
            if(Regex.IsMatch(_wb.DocumentText, alertRegexPattern))
                _wb.DocumentText = Regex.Replace(_wb.DocumentText, alertRegexPattern, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Sources/Resources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx
- http://regexpal.com/
- (Sorry, had more but SO will only let me post 2 links)